# Magento 2: Change Customer Group Once Order is Completed for Product

Tags: magento2, admin, orders, event-observer, sales-order

I have to change Customer Group.

**Once Customer has purchased X Product & Order Status is Completed.**
In Order apart from X Product if there are any other products then no issue.

Don't wanna use Cron Job. **Can manage through Observer?**

On Admin Side Once we Click on "Ship", it changes Status to "Completed". So need to execute the event on click of that?

Which Event needs to Call?

Followed below links

[Change customer group upon buying a specific product](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/59827/change-customer-group-upon-buying-a-specific-product)

https://cyrillschumacher.com/magento2-list-of-all-dispatched-events/

https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/magento-2-events.html

Comment: Can this extension help you? https://magecomp.com/magento-2-auto-customer-group-switching.html

Answer (score 0):

- Listening all states of order change: `sales_order_save_after`: [What's the best event/way to listen for all order state changes in Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/125058/whats-the-best-event-way-to-listen-for-all-order-state-changes-in-magento-2/125063#125063). There are some default states: `new, pending_payment, processing, complete, closed, canceled, holded, payment_review`.
- For shipment event, we can use: `sales_order_shipment_save_after`

Comment: From Admin By clicking on "Submit Shipment" it's not calling

Comment: You catch `sales_order_shipment_save_after`?

Comment: `<event name="sales_order_shipment_save_after">
        <observer name="change_user_Group" instance="Custom\Module\Observer\ChangeUserGroupObserver" />
    </event>` i have created file in my custom module located @ `magento\app\code\Custom\Module\etc\adminhtml\events.xml`

Comment: Try to get some info: `$shipment = $observer->getEvent()->getShipment();
        /** @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order */
        $order = $shipment->getOrder();`

Comment: @AnkitShah You can get the shipment info?